# React won't load bootstrap font loader error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react project which also loads bootstrap.css.

I am getting this compiler error:

```
Error: Module parse failed: /Users/me/myproject/app/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

What does it mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working with webpack you will need a url-loader or a file-loader for fonts:

```
{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader:'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```

**EDIT** 
You can read the [Docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) about webpack loaders.
you should learn about loaders or webpack in general, basically what this specific loader does is checking the size of each relevant file (according to the regex in the `test`) and if it below the limit it will insert it to the bundle as Data Url / base64 string. if it above the limit it will fallback to the `file-loader` and will serve it as a resource assets.
you can read about these loaders [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader)

Comment: where do I add this...package.json?

Comment: in webpack.config.js file

Comment: Inside this section?

Comment: module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

Comment: @JakeBrown777 i've edit my answer, theres a link to the webpack's documentation of loaders.

Comment: Could you please check out the loaders code above? It's the current code for the loaders. Can't understand what to do and I've read the docs :o/